# С++ и функции с переменным количеством агрументов

Tags: c++, c

Допустим у нас есть функция

```
void foo(int a, ...)
```

и функция

```
void bar(int a, ...)
```

Вопрос: как в функции `bar()` можно вызвать функцию `foo()` так, что бы добавить пару своих аргументов и передать все которые ей пришли?

Например: вызываем `bar(1,2,3,4,5)` и нужно что бы в функции `bar` было вызвано `foo(1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20)`.

P. S. Функции не обязательно должны принимать `int`.

Например

```
typedef void (*EndFunction)(...);

void endFunction(double a, double b, int c, void* d) {

}

EndFunction someEndFunction = (EndFunction) endFunction;

void recieverFunction(SomeParamStack* stack, ...) {
    if(stack->empty()) someEndFunction(/* вот тут нужно поместить список аргументов */);
    else switch (stack->getNextType()) {
        case(ST_INT) : {
            recieverFunction(stack,/* аргументов */,stack->getInt(),);
            break;
        }

        case(ST_DOUBLE) : {
            recieverFunction(stack,/* аргументов */, stack->getDouble());
            break;
        }

        case(ST_POINTER) : {
            recieverFunction(stack,/* аргументов */, stack->getPointer());
            break;
        }
    }
}




int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
    SomeParamStack stack;
    stack->pushPointer(0);
    stack->pushInt(3);
    stack->pushDouble(2.2);
    stack->pushDouble(1.1);
    recieverFunction(stack);
}
```

Comment: а просто `foo(1,2,3,a)` нельзя?)

Comment: нет)) у меня задумано это рекурсивно, поэтому и никак)) по сути нужно накопить аргументы а потом вызвать уже нужную функцию)

Comment: [man stdarg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) функции с переменным числом аргументов (например, printf()) м.б. Вы это имели в виду?

Comment: *функции не обязательно должны принимать int* -- но при этом все аргументы одного типа, или разных?

Comment: используйте std::vector/std::list  в качестве аргумента. Это решит все вопросы.

Comment: @Артем Как ваши функции узнают, сколько им было передано аргументов?

Comment: Откровенно говоря, проект вызывает большие вопросы, зачем так сложно... Я поначалу думал, что имеется некоторая *чужая* функция, и приходится извращаться под нее, но самому у себя городить такое?...

Comment: Опишите подробнее, 1) как у Вас foo/bar узнают количество и типы переданных им аргументов? 2) если это ваши собственные функции, то м.б. поступить проще и передавать в них вектора указателей?

Answer (score 3):

Сделать функцию, принимающую список параметров - по аналогии с `vprintf` - не годится?

```
void foo(int count, va_list vlist)
{
    if (count == 0) return;
    va_list ap;
    va_copy(ap,vlist);
    printf("Count = %d, value = %d\n",count,va_arg(ap,int));
    foo(count-1,ap);
    va_end(ap);
};


void foo(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,count);
    foo(count,ap);
    va_end(ap);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
     foo(5,1,2,3,4,5);
}
```

Comment: к сожалению нет.

Comment: Посмотрите мое решение - что в нем вам не нравится? Два варианта, рекурсия - что вам не так? :)

Comment: данное решение будет работать в таком случае?

Comment: Так ведь работает же... Вы поясните, что именно вы хотите - передавать из bar в foo **измененные** данные? Как именно измененные? У вас какой-то отдельный пример.

Comment: вот в таком случае будет работать? http://pastebin.com/qbuzMMyP

Comment: Вы хотите добавлять что-то после троеточия, грубо говоря. Это можно, но это будет не переносимо. Просто потому, что стандарт запрещает что-либо передавать после троеточия. В этом случае лучше переходить к шаблонам, но я так понимаю, это не ваш случай?

Comment: именно не мой случай(( к сожалению нужно передавать полученные аргументы в обычную функцию

Comment: @Артем, глянул на ваш пастебин. Такая задумка не программируестя (по крайней мере переносимо и обобщенно). Придется все с соответствующими дескрипторами тянуть в структуре, на которую указывает `stack`, а все функции вроде `endFunction` должны уметь работать с этой структурой.

Answer (score -2):

```
void foo(double a,...) //Так объявляется функция с заранее неизвестным числом параметров
{
  double *P=&a; //Взятие адреса у первого параметра
  double sum=0; //Инициализация значения суммы в ноль

  while (*P) //Пока встречаются параметры и параметр не равен 0
   {
     sum=sum+(*P);//Прибавляем к сумме то что взяли по адресу P 
     P++; //Адресная арифметика. Смена текущего адреса на следующий
   }


  cout<<sum<<endl; //Вывод результата на экран
}

void bar(double a,...) 
{
  double *P=&a; 
  double i=0, fooi=0;;

 double[] fooArgs = new double[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
  double[] *resArgs = new double[500];
  foo
  while (*P) 
   {
     sum=sum+(*P);//Адресная арифметика. Смена текущего адреса на следующий
     resArgs[++i] = fooArgs[++fooi];
     resArgs[++i] = (*P);

   }

   foo(resArgs);
}
```

Comment: Непереносимо. Есть же стандартные вещи - `va_list`, к чему эти извращения?...

Comment: @Harry старая  школа. не знал про va_list , если честно

Comment: Ээээ??!! Это в языке со времен Кернигана и Ритчи... Это скорее новая школа об этом не помнит :)

Comment: @Harry вопрос, а стандарт что-то гарантирует, что список аргументов через указатель вот так можно итерировать? Ну обычные параметры например нельзя. И да, а что кроме `va_list` есть в таких случаях? Всегда его использовал, хотя вроде не старый...

Comment: Вряд ли это будет работать (по крайней мере в x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: @pavel Это к автору ответа...

Comment: @pavel переносимые способы это `va_list` и иже с ними. Всё остальное - от лукавого.